# asp.net form authentication timeout settings ignored

Tags: asp.net, authentication, timeout

In web.config I've configured forms authentication as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx"
        timeout="20"
        slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

Initially the ASPXAUTH cookie is set correctly. Using Firefox's cookie viewer I can see the cookie and the expiration period is correct (20 mins).

Sliding expiration also sets an updated cookie correctly (20 more mins added).

But after that any new http request (even if made within the next 5 mins) will result in 302 error and redirects to Login.aspx as if authentication has expired.

Application details below:
target asp.net 4
iis 7.5
shared hosting but with dedicated pool (recycling did not help).
Login.aspx uses the asp Login control for authentication (no custom cookie).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This could have many reasons.

Is this happening on your local machine, too? Have you maybe configured a httpCookie Domain in  web.config which doesn`t match your local host environment?

Have you configured a machinekey (validation/encryption)? This can be important in load balanced scenarios.

Do you use dynamic content caching in IIS?

Have a look into your event log. Per default 302 errors based on a failed forms authentication are logged there. Are there any entries telling why you have are considered being unauthenticated? It could help identifying the root cause (ticket expired, could not be decrypted etc.)

Also keep in mind, that the expiration of a forms authentication cookie is not extended on each request. A forms authentication cookie is refreshed after 50% of the original timeout has passed (in your case 10 mins). So configure your session timeout appropriately.

Comment: 1) no, in local machine everything works as expected. 2) I haven't used machineKey but I am currently testing. 3) FWIW, my host replied that I cannot use Session as this is shared hosting. But I am only using Forms Authentication (no Session variables). Does Forms Authentication depend on Session? If so, is there a way to configure it otherwise?

Comment: No, but one see it quite often that session life time is connected to the authentication. So if the session timeout, the forms authentication cookie is removed. However, if the stated problem resides on the server only, have you added http CookieDomain to your web.config? Also check, if the response header after the successfull login contains a "Set-Cookie" Key. Additionally, if you click on a page after login, the cookie should be part of the request header.

Comment: Firefox's network monitor indicated the cookie is part of every request. Anyway, I've added machineKey and does the trick so far...